# Rails JSON data from other domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to get JSON data from other domain. I used this code:

```
class EMPInfoController < ApplicationController
require 'httparty'

 def empdata 
  uri = HTTParty.get("http://www.somesite.com/jsondata/xyz")
  resp = JSON.parse(uri.body)
  @empdata = resp
 end

end
```

I am able to get the JSON data parsed to `resp` however when I push it to `@empdata` and try to use it using JavaScript it does not seem to find the right keys/hashes.

Is there a way to dissect the JSON hash and get the output to view?

```
JSON Data - resp
{
 "empid123456": {
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "title": "mr",
    "age": "32",
    "blood_group": "B+"
 }
}
```

Can I get it by simply moving it to `@EmpData` and use `@EmpData[:first_name]` to retreive it later in view?

I am new with Rails and need some guidance on every step of my project.

Comment: is `empid123456` key static or dynamic? or did you want to write emp:{"id":"123456",.....

Comment: I don't really get your question. Do you want to know, how you can pass the JSON Object to your client side JavaScript?

Comment: @pette - empid is dynamic in my real problem, it is called based on param - query string however in above situation lets assume that it is static

Comment: @PeterSorowka - I need help with getting data withing rails views.. I am not sure If we can use javascript directly with other portal to do ajax call however if there is any other method to get my data using javascript on json page created.. please suggest

Comment: Do you want the server to *only* return the JSON string or need it to be embedded within a template? In any case I think you can skip parsing the JSON file on the server side and just output the `uri.body` directly (except any error handling of course)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your JSON data in a Ruby class and put it in your "models" directory as `app/models/json_data.rb`:

```
class JsonData
  attr_reader :emp

  def initialize(attributes)
   @emp = attributes[:emp]
  end

  def self.from_json(json_string)
    parsed = JSON.parse(json_string)
    emp = Emp.new(parsed['empid123456'])
    new(:emp => emp)
  end
end
```

Create an Active Model class for the `emp` and place it in `app/models/emp.rb`:

```
class Emp
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  ATTRIBUTES =  [:first_name, :last_name, :title, :age, :blood_group]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
   ###add your activemodel validations here ###

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    self.attributes = attributes
  end

  def attributes
    ATTRIBUTES.inject(
    ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
    ) do |result, key|
      result[key] = read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      result
    end
  end

  def attributes= (attrs)
    attrs.each_pair {|k, v| send("#{k}=", v)}
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    send(key)
  end
end
```

In your controller you can now do this:

```
def empdata 
  uri = HTTParty.get("http://www.somesite.com/jsondata/xyz")
  @empdata = JsonData.from_json(uri.body)
end
```

In your view you can use:

```
@empdata.first_name
@empdata.last_name
```

to retrieve the respective values.

Comment: Wow, this looks quite over engineered. The OP didn't ask for validation. To just achieve your latter point it might be sufficient to build an OpenStruct object...

Comment: @pette - thanks however it keeps giving me NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/json_data.rb:10:in `from_json'

Comment: @Andy i have edited the code in json_data.rb. and emp.rb But this will only work if empdata123456 is static and does not change depending on request parameters.

Comment: @pette still not getting it to work.. now it seems to break at getting  each_pair.. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. Also the new issue is still there.. let me clarify.. the json data is from other domain(non local)

Comment: If it is breaking on `each_pair`, it means that the json object keys do not correspond with your emp object's attributes. Ensure all the keys in `empid123456` json object are in `ATTRIBUTES=[....]` line in your Emp model.

Comment: It does not matter whether you are fetching the json from your local machine or from another domain. The only thing you have to be sure is that you are receiving the json data.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.. Thanks @pette

```
@first_name = []
@last_name = []
@title = [] 
@age = []
@blood_group = []
thixjs = "#{emp}.json"
resp.each do |key_category, group_category|
  group_category.each do |key,val|
    if group_category.is_a? Array
      eval("@#{key}") << val
    elsif group_category.is_a? Hash
      if key == thixjs
      else
        eval("@#{key}") << val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However this is taking time to resolve, but for now it will do.

Thanks again.